# SqlServer >> View syncronization status

Tags: sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I have two sql servers with repl-merge replication, on the subscriber server in Local Subscription if I tried to view Syncronization status I got windows with last status message "The specific pull subscription is not configured with a syncronization agent job. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider).. If Click Start error msg is displayed

> The agent could not be started.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
> batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The specified pull subscription is not configured with a
> synchronization agent job. Changed database context to 'WIL_DAT'.
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 21848)

I forget how I reach to this message,

[edit] I remembered how, If I press view job history in the viewsyncronization status window this error shows up

> The specified @job_id ('7C1D697D-BC8C-4536-9FB3-C8C26CCF2A7E') does
> not exist. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14262)

this error because the job in subscriber server in Sql Server agent  was deleted, and new job is created with different id in msdb.dbo.sysjobs

the new job is working fine and the merge replication is working except the replication monitor is not working

how to solve this problem.